# Type nested object typescript

Tags: typescript

I have below object in typescript

```
    let peers:any = {
key:{initiator:isInitiator1,config: configuration1,stream: localStream1}, 
key:{initiator:isInitiator2, config: configuration2, stream: localStream2},
key:{initiator:isInitiator2, config: configuration2, stream: localStream2}};
```

what is the best possible way to declare above variable with typescript without "any" ?

I need to access each object like this `peers[connUserSocketId]`

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest is to define an interface that describes the structure. You can change to class if you will have also additional methods to process the data.

Here is a sample interface based on the provided sample if I understood your structure correctly. You want to store multiple of the same record by some key.

```
interface Peers {
   [key: string]: { 
      initiator: boolean, 
      config: any/* Type of config */, 
      stream: any /* Type of stream */ 
   }
}
```

Then you define real values like this:

```
const peers: Peers = {
   key1: { initiator: true, config: {}, stream: {} },
   key2: { initiator: false, config: {}, stream: {} } 
}
```